# Oracle configuration. "create or replace" function create invalid object

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, configuration, database-trigger

I recently moved my database to a new server (both Oracle 11g).
In the new host, there is a weird behavior, that whenever I run something like:

```
create or replace test_trigger
   before insert or update
   on test_table
   for each row
begin
   select 1 from dual;
end;
/
```

The trigger created is invalid without any error in log. I tried to recompile, it still invalid.

It only happen with the function "create or replace". If I drop the trigger and re-create again, it would be valid.

My question is, did I config something incorrectly? How can I check it? Thank you.

Comment: *" If I drop the trigger and re-create again, it would be valid."* Valid? Not the posted trigger it wouldn't.

Comment: Running this command should give you the error message in Littlefoot's answer. I'm not sure what you mean by there's not error in "log". It should be there in your sqlplus output, assuming that's what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Code you posted won't compile, not in any Oracle database I know. Why? Wrong syntax.

Here's a demonstration:

```
SQL> create or replace test_trigger
  2     before insert or update
  3     on test_table
  4     for each row
  5  begin
  6     select 1 from dual;
create or replace test_trigger
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


SQL> end;
SP2-0042: unknown command "end" - rest of line ignored.
SQL> /
```

So, what's wrong with it?

- create (or replace) wants to know **what** you're going to create. "test_trigger"? As far as Oracle is concerned, that could be "mickey_mouse" and the result will be the same. It is the `trigger` keyword that is missing
- `SELECT` in `PL/SQL` requires an `INTO` clause, so that you could store the result into something
- in order to be able to do that, you have to `declare` a variable

Here's code that, actually, compiles:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test_trigger   --> this
  2     before insert or update
  3     on test_table
  4     for each row
  5  declare
  6    l_dummy number;     --> this
  7  begin
  8     select 1
  9     into l_dummy       --> this
 10     from dual;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

So, it seems that you misinterpret reality.

Comment: you're right normally the answer should be this related to the given syntax, but OP asks about the weird behaviour of the current situation.

Comment: Aha; I think I get your point, @Barbaros. You (and the OP) are saying that Oracle just won't execute `create or replace`, but `drop + create` instead. Well, if that's the case, a full environment versions (Oracle + operating system) *might* help. Metalink could provide some more info as well. If nothing helps, a service request should be opened.